# How can I give data from my webworker to highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, web-worker

I am working with highcharts, I want to update highcharts series from my web-worker. My web-worker is receiving data from my api via xmlhttprequest now I want to update my chart without refreshing the web page , and how can I  pass that data to highcharts series?

Comment: That really depends on your data format you are getting back and if you want to completely overwrite the existing data in the chart or just update data points and/or add new data point.

Comment: I am getting json back and I want to only update the points. Its line chart I want to move line according to data

Comment: If your xAxis is not going to change you can do `series.setData` - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData.

Comment: If you are getting in a new data point you can use `series.addPoint` - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint. This gives you options to shift data over or just append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the onMessage event, and post messages from the worker to the client. Messages should be stringyfied object or arrays.

In your main code:

```
var worker = new Worker('w/main-worker.js');
worker.postMessage('message to worker');

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    // do stuff with data from worker
};
```

In your worker:

```
// do stuff
// when stuff is ready
postMessage(myStuff);

// handle messages from the main thread
onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    // do stuff with message from main thread
};
```

I have few demos here: https://github.com/mchaov/WebWorkers There are demos for similar use case like yours.